# What's the best way to share folder between guest and host machine in VMWARE over VPN?

Tags: vmware, vpn, shared-folders

i have a win 7 host machine and i'm running my vmware which is a win server machine.

So i'm doing windows development work on my vmware.

the source codes are in my win 7 machine which i access using a shared folder method.

My only problem now is when my vmware connects to VPN to the deploy the codes, the folder gets disconnected.

as i don't really understand the networking or the vmware architecture, what can i do so that i can share the folder from my win 7 host machine to my vmware without getting disconnected when i connect to VPN using my guest (win server) machine?

please advise.

stuck on vmware

thanks

Comment: Which VPN client?

Comment: Cisco VPN client.

Comment: Two more questions: have you configured the networking in your VM to be a) host-only or b) bridged? And when you're connected to VPN, can you get to any other machines on your internal network (another system at home, a printer, etc)?

Comment: using NAT and no.